# How can I make a clickable UILabel in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to make a clickable `UILabel` by following this code:

```
class ViewNotificationsDetails: UIViewController {    
   @IBOutlet weak var back: UILabel!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewNotificationsDetails.tapFunction))
          back.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
          back.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
      }

      @objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
          print("tap working")
      } 
}
```

But when executing the code, I get the error ->

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value on the line "back.isUserInteractionEnabled = true".

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is your label properly connected to the Label ?

Comment: Are you sure you connected the outlet in interface builder?

Comment: That was the problem. Now it works correctly
I was sure that my label was correctly connected to the label..

Thanks

Comment: By marking an answer as accepted you are telling others that the question has been solved. You don't need to append that into the title. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your Label memory allocation. You have created `IBOutlet` of label but not connected it with Interface from your Storyboard/XIB view controller.

> Go to your Interface Builder: (Storyboard/XIB) View Controller ▶ Select 'Connection Inspector' ▶ Connect label outlet 'back' with Label interface element

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I thought the connection was well made, but I had to delete it without wanting to and that was the problem.
I just did this and a problem works.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

try this code, is working well with me

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var cliclableLable: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction))
    cliclableLable.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cliclableLable.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap working")
}
```

}

also don't forget to link your label with the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `back.userInteractionEnabled = true`
you did wrong as isUserInteractionEnabled.

Comment: When I wrote that, I received an error. The problem is the UILAbel was not correctly connected to the label. Thanks.

Comment: are you using Storyboard?

Comment: connect like above image of @Krunal's answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: If you are trying to achieve using storyboard, here is a simple way.]

Add a UIButton element on the label. clear button placeholder, make button constraints equal to the label i.e equal height, equal width, Top, bottom. In the above image, label has only trailing fixed as it expands wrt text. so button trailing should be to trailing to the label. No leading constraint to the button in the below context. Finally created an IBAction and write your code to get your task done.